# How to create a multilevel dictionary in the YAML metadata of R Markdown?

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

While using a single level list/dictionary for parameterizing an `rmarkdown` document works:

````
---
params:
  first_level: ~
---

```{r}
params
```
````

and knitting returns the expected

```
## $first_level
## NULL
```

I'm unable to use multi-level list/dictionaries as knitting

````
---
params:
  first_level:
    second_level: ~
---

```{r}
params
```
````

produces `Error: no value field specified for YAML parameter 'first_level'
Execution halted`, where I would expect

```
## $first_level
## $first_level$second_level
## NULL
```

Is there really only a single level list supported or what am I screwing up?

As I commented below, the expected output can be achieved using

````
---
params:
  first_level: !r list(second_level = NULL)
---

```{r}
params
```
````

But why use `yaml` then at all in place of a parametrizing code block?

Comment: You can just use 2 levels and the second levels name has to be `value`. Try this: `params:  first_level:   value: ~`. Changing `value` to `second_level` will give the error ...

Comment: Making the content of `first_level` into `!r list(second_level = NULL)` produces what I want/expect, but defeats the use of `yaml` to begin with ...

Comment: I think this is a bug of the RStudio IDE (because `rmarkdown::render()` works). You may file it to https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie. [Done](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1752).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is a special field for R Markdown, and you must use one of the two ways to specify the value of a parameter: if the value is not a list (e.g., a scalar), you can specify it using the normal YAML syntax; however, if it is a list, R Markdown expects a sub-field named `value`, and the value must be specified in this sub-field. In your case, you must use a `value` field, e.g.,

````
---
params:
  first_level:
    value:
      second_level: ~
---

```{r}
params
```
````

That is currently [by design](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html).